# Appending data to JSON column - Rails 4, Postgres

Tags: json, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Model `Listing` has a `json` column named `vendors`, which defaults to `{}`:

```
add_column :listings, :vendors, :json, null: false, default: {
  hd: {}
  ...
  }
end
```

Inside the `Listing` class, I am trying to `merge!` in a hash to `hd: {..}` like so:

```
def self.append_vendor_attrs(sku)
  listing = find_by(sku: sku) || Listing.new(sku: sku)
  listing.vendors[:hd].merge!({ foo: 'bar' })
  listing.vendors_will_change!
  listing.save! # throws no exceptions in the log
end
```

but `vendors[:hd]` remains empty. if I try to replicate this manually with:

```
l = Listing.create... 
l.vendors[:hd].merge!({ foo:'bar' })
```

my hash persists.

Comment: Have  you tried moving `listing.vendors_will_change!` above the line where you modify the attribute in place? My hunch is that the code you have in your method tells AR that the value of the attribute *was* the new value, so that it doesn't see the object as dirty when you call `save!`.

Comment: @hoffm  of course! I was calling `will_change` after the data was already appended, triggering AR to "listen" to any changes to that row but nothing was changed. Go Brooklyn! Turn this into an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Glad it worked! I just added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `listing.vendors_will_change!` tells Active Record that the value of the attribute "was" the new value. From AR's perspective, then, the old and new values match, and so the record is not dirty when you call `save!`.

The fix is to move `listing.vendors_will_change!` above the line where you modify the attribute. So the new code will look like this:

```
def self.append_vendor_attrs(sku)
  listing = find_by(sku: sku) || Listing.new(sku: sku)
  listing.vendors_will_change!
  listing.vendors[:hd].merge!({ foo: 'bar' })
  listing.save! # throws no exceptions in the log
end
```